# jQuery click stops css hover events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a classical css drop-down menu with css hover selector switching to "display:block;"

In order to work with touch devices, I have added this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $("div.menuHead").click(function () {
        //Toggle the menu but don't include it in the hide selector using .not()
        $(this).siblings("div.menu").toggle();
        $("div.menuHead").not($(this)).siblings("div.menu").hide();
});
});
```

The hover drop-down continues working on desktops, while the menu can be clicked on a touch device. **However, if the desktop user happens to click with the mouse, it works but completely disables hovering on all menus**. Then only clicking works.

Any idea why? I have tried disabling css hover properties completely, and handling everything in jQuery with mouseover and mouseout events, but when clicking iOs triggers a mouseover then a click event immediately, which open-closes the menu very quickly, so it does not work.

Html structure:

```
<div class="vectorMenu">
    <div class="menuHead">Menu Title</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Amongst other things I have set in CSS:

```
div.vectorMenu div.menu {
    display: none;
}

div.vectorMenu:hover div.menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks,

Etienne

Comment: I put an answer based off what I can see here but a JSfiddle with the full code would be much more useful to help you with

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parenthesis on `.hide`. It should be:

```
$("div.menuHead").not($(this)).siblings("div.menu").hide();
```

Comment: And `.not($(this))` can be replaced with `.not(this)`.

Comment: This is a typo, the original code was correct. It still has the same behavior : css hover show/hide works only until the first click.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT *(based on fiddle produced by OP)*:

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74jvF/)

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuHead").on('click mouseenter mouseleave', '> li', function (evt) {
        var e = evt || window.event;
        switch (e.type || e.which) {
            case "click":
                if (!($(this).find('.menu').hasClass('stayOpen'))) {
                    $('.stayOpen').removeClass('stayOpen').hide();
                    $(this).find('.menu').addClass('stayOpen');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('.menu').removeClass('stayOpen').hide();
                }
                break;
            case "mouseenter":
                $(this).find('.menu').not('.stayOpen').addClass('open').show();
                break;
            case "mouseleave":
                $(this).find('.menu').not('.stayOpen').removeClass('open').hide();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<ul class="menuHead">
    <li class="title">Menu #1
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Menu #1 - Link #1</li>
            <li>Menu #1 - Link #2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Menu #2
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Menu #2 - Link #1</li>
            <li>Menu #2 - Link #2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
.title {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    display: none;
}
.open,
.stayOpen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: show instead of toggle will not allow closing the menu by clicking again, one will stay open forever. That's not ideal

Comment: Initial display:none; is already set to make pure-css hover dropdown, of course

Comment: > .menu will not work, menu is a sibling and not a child of .menuHead

Comment: wait why is it a sibling

Comment: The question is about css hover which does not work anymore after the first click handled by jQuery, nothing else. I posted more details in the question. There is no hover in your example!

Comment: You should be able to use this now.  New demo located here: http://jsfiddle.net/74jvF/ and code updated in post.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with pure CSS by adding `!important` to `:hover` CSS:

```
div.vectorMenu:hover div.menu {
    display: block !important;
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo