# jquery menu nested list & toggle function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hi i am trying to make a simple menu with dropdown.
with a simple nested list. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="niv0">
      <a href="#" class="has_ssmenu closed">Rubrique</a>
      <ul class="ssmenu">
         <li class="niv1">
         <a href="#">Sous-rubrique</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="niv0">
       <a href="#" class="has_ssmenu closed">Rubrique</a>
       <ul class="ssmenu">
          <li class="niv1">
              <a href="#">ssrub</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" niv0">
       <a href="#">rubrique</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I would like, on a click on '.has_ssmenu', the nested list slideToggle or fade and add an '.open' class to it, and of course if there was already a list toggled, close it and remove the '.open' class from it.

My actual jquery code is like that:

```
       $('.ssmenu').css( 'display','none');

var open = false;
$('.has_ssmenu').toggle(
    function() {
        if (open == false){
            //if its the first time
            $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
            $(this).next().addClass("ssmenu_open");
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
            open=true;
        }
        else{
            //if there is already a list opened
            $('.ssmenu_open').slideToggle(50);
            $('.has_ssmenu').next().removeClass("ssmenu_open");
            $('.has_ssmenu').removeClass("open");
            $('.has_ssmenu').addClass("closed");
            $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
            $(this).next().addClass("ssmenu_open");
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
        }   
    },
    function() {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).addClass("closed");
            $(this).next().removeClass("ssmenu_open");
            $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
            open=false;
    });
```

But it dont work :( 
I cant deal with the multiple link. How to stop the toggle if i click on an other link ?

Actually with my code, its ok for the first click, if you choose an other link it's still ok: the first opened list is close. 
But then if you click again on the first link who is now closed, my code bug. He dont get the open class, and he dont close the second opened list.

Maybe there is an easiest way to do it ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite literally I *just did this for someone else*.  Use this and adapt your code around it:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7dpZ/)

### HTML:

```
<ul class="menuHead">
    <li class="title">Menu #1
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Menu #1 - Link #1</li>
            <li>Menu #1 - Link #2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Menu #2
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Menu #2 - Link #1</li>
            <li>Menu #2 - Link #2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuHead").on('click mouseenter mouseleave', '> li', function (evt) {
        var e = evt || window.event;
        switch (e.type || e.which) {
            case "click":
                if (!($(this).find('.menu').hasClass('stayOpen'))) {
                    $('.stayOpen').fadeOut('fast').removeClass('stayOpen');
                    $(this).find('.menu').addClass('stayOpen');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('.menu').fadeOut('fast').removeClass('stayOpen');
                }
                break;
            case "mouseenter":
                $(this).find('.menu').not('.stayOpen').fadeIn('fast').addClass('open');
                break;
            case "mouseleave":
                $(this).find('.menu').not('.stayOpen').fadeOut('fast').removeClass('open');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

### CSS:

```
.title {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    width: 300px;
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.open,
.stayOpen {
    display: block;
}
```

He never accepted as an answer so maybe you'll make better use of it.  [Here's his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671219/jquery-click-stops-css-hover-events/20671481#20671481)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I modifiy your code and now its work for me. I use a toggle instead of click because like the event is on a <a> i got some trouble with the click function. Dont know if there is a way to use click function on a <a> and desactived the "url".  Also your code is intersting, maybe you could comment the part with break and var e = evt || window.event;
        switch (e.type || e.which) (for pedagogy)

Comment: yeah you can disable the URL part but you also don't actually need to use `<a>` for this if you aren't utilizing the hyperlink. anything can be given a click event.  but if you really like using an anchor (`<a>`) then just put `e.prevent default();` just after where I have the `var e = evt || window.event;` and if this answer worked for you, feel free to up vote . I'll explain the `var e = ... switch (e.type ...)` in another comment :)

Comment: OK thanks i will try this next time i nedd it. I cant vote for you for the moment need more reputation, but you got all my considération ;-)

Comment: no worries!  just glad to help.  To understand why I used the conditional `var` assignment for e - `var e = this || that` - this equivalent to saying `if (this) {var e = this} else {var e = that};` It basically just tries to equate `var e` to the first argument and if it is BOOLEAN FALSE (undefined, null, etc - see http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html#the_boolean_data_type) it moves on to the next one.  I do this because Microsoft uses window.event but W3C spec allows passing the event through as an argument to the function (aka, `evt`)

Answer (score 0):

OK it works fine know. is use this:

```
$('.ssmenu').css( 'display','none');

$('.has_ssmenu').toggle(function() {
                if (!($(this).next().hasClass('ssmenu_open'))) {
                    $('.has_ssmenu').removeClass('open');
                    $('.ssmenu_open').css( 'display','none').removeClass('ssmenu_open');
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(400).addClass('ssmenu_open');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                    $(this).next().fadeOut('fast').removeClass('ssmenu_open');
                }
         },
         function(){
                if (!($(this).next().hasClass('ssmenu_open'))) {
                    $('.has_ssmenu').removeClass('open');
                    $('.ssmenu_open').css( 'display','none').removeClass('ssmenu_open');
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(400).addClass('ssmenu_open');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                    $(this).next().fadeOut('fast').removeClass('ssmenu_open');
                }

         });
```

For this Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="niv0">
      <a href="#" class="has_ssmenu">Rubrique</a>
      <ul class="ssmenu">
         <li class="niv1">
         <a href="#">Sous-rubrique</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="niv0">
       <a href="#" class="has_ssmenu">Rubrique</a>
       <ul class="ssmenu">
          <li class="niv1">
              <a href="#">ssrub</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" niv0">
       <a href="#">rubrique</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The .open class is used to add som css3 feature:

```
#menu{
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;  
    }
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;  
    }
#menu li a{
    color: #CCC;
    position: relative
    }
#menu li > a:not(:only-child):after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 5px 0 ;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
}
#menu li > a.open:before{
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 38px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.ssmenu{
    background: #4F97A7;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.ssmenu a {
    color: #fff;
}
```